# How can I access a variable when I've outsourced my models in a own package

Tags: go

Hi guys and thanks in advance for your help! :)

I try to learn Go and wanna ask how I can access a variable defined in a struct in an own class. How do you make your models in go? I really wanna put the models in a own class.

When I do this I cant access the Variables of my struct Student.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/nikolastankovic/hello/models"
)

func main() {
    var nikola models.Student
    nikola.name = "nikola" // THIS DOESN'T WORK :(
    fmt.Println(nikola)
}
```

Model Student in subpackage models:

```
package models

type Student struct {
    name string
    number int
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the attribute `name` with a capital letter `N` and it will work.
Like this:

```
package models

type Student struct {
    Name string
    Number int
}
```

Small letter means unexported (private) in Go and capital letter means exported (public).
Also see: [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/basics/3)

Comment: Hi Bazzz! Thanks a lot for your answer. Now I understand ...It works :)

Comment: Hi Nikola, good to hear that you managed to solve the issue. Please tick my answer as "correct" so that others who use search to find a solution will see that this is the correct one.

Comment: Sure Bazzz :) I just can't 'cause I've to wait some minutes. But then I'll definitively :)